# Html links and fill label

Tags: html

How can I enter some page using html and make it automatic search for some videos by my entered word?
I have an example from my college where it fills mail app with info, who to sent, cc, subject and body.

```
<a href="mailto:mirko@mirkovic.hr?
   cc=marko@markovic.hr&
   subject=Javljanje&
   body=Pozdrav">
```

As this, I tried this on youtube, but I have no idea what to set like "Search" or "Pretraživanje" which is written in label... Any ideas?

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com?
    Pretraživanje=programming"
```

Comment: https://youtube.com/results?search_query=programming


However, you should have a youtube api developers to even go deeper into programming. Your example as above applies to mailto:... But if you are trying to perform a search and return results then you will need a proper javascript code that you will need to develope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube uses the "search_query" parameter. If you search for "Planet Earth", the resulting URL looks like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Planet+Earth
```

Set the "search_query" parameter to whatever you want to search for, with each word separated by a plus "+" sign.

Comment: Oh..ok. But, where can I find this info for other web pages?

Comment: This info would be unique to whatever web page you are using. Perhaps they use a similar search query parameter, or perhaps it is done entirely differently. You would need knowledge of the site's API to do this successfully. You may have success testing a particular site's search functionality just like YouTube, but results are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using YouTube exclusively you can construct a URL to bring a person to the results page of the query you are looking for.  Here is an example of what I mean.

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=stuff+and+things"
```

In this case the serach was for stuff and things.  However you can put any words you want into the query, just seperate each word with a `+`.